# python dataframe using nested for loop to get cost sum for flagged combination of 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

Supposed this is the first 3 rows of the dataset, rest looks similar.
And there can be more than 3 books. lets say 6 books.

```
a=[['a',1,1,0,123],['b',1,0,1,153],['c',0,1,1,126]] 
df= pd.DataFrame(a,columns=['id','book1','book2','book3','cost']) 
print(df)

id  book_1  book_2  book_3  cost
a   1         1      0      123
b   1         0      1      154
c   0         1      1      159
```

I want to have a nested for loop (or anything, I can only think of for loop)
to get the sum of cost.
The desired progress should be like
I want the sum of cost of in row where (book1 and book2 ==1) , then the for loop will continue to (book1 and book3 ==1), until (book1 and bookN ==1) is finished.
then start (book2 and book3 ==1) until (book2 and bookN ==1) is finished.
And repeat the process

Comment: import pandas as pd 
a=[['a',1,1,0,123],['b',1,0,1,153],['c',0,1,1,126]]
df= pd.DataFrame(a,columns=['id','book1','book2','book3','cost'])
print(df)
The format is a little messed up, there is like an example how dataset should look like

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are after:

```
df["Total"] = df["cost"] * (df["book1"]+df["book2"]+df["book3"])
df["Total"].sum()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).